# Cefsharp randomly not initializing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, chromium-embedded

Cefsharp sometimes fails to init. The control stays blank, nothing happens. But as soon as I restart the program, it works. It's completely random, and it always gets fixed by restarting.

Since it's completely random, I don't know how to handle this error, or even know what is causing it.

I have some buttons over the Browser which load flawlessly, but the browser appears blank.

I tried to put a breakpoint in this if

```
if (Browser == null)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

on MetroWindow_Loaded event, yet it's not triggering, so the browser is not null, but something is failing to init.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this bug?

Thanks

Edit:

I load a static html which loads a google maps v3. This executes in the MetroWindow_Loaded event:

```
        var html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@".\Resources\Mapa.html");
        Browser.LoadHtml(html);
```

This is the XAML tag

```
<wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"  x:Name="Browser" ConsoleMessage="Browser_OnConsoleMessage" LoadingStateChanged="Browser_OnLoadingStateChanged"/>
```

Edit2: so I executed manually these lines when the bug appeared:

```
 var html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@".\Resources\Mapa.html");
        Browser.LoadHtml(html);
```

and the browser loaded so:

Browser is not null and is not failing to initialize, but either 
a) metroWindow_Loaded is not firing
b) metroWindow_Loaded is firing "too soon" and therefore Browser.LoadHtml(html) not loading the HTML.

is there a more appropiate event to run this code?

Edit3: This is how MainWindow inits, maybe it's worth mentioning.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _mapaController = new MapaController(this);
    Browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("boundAsync", _mapaController, BindingOptions.DefaultBinder);
    var login = new LoginView();
    var res = login.ShowDialog(); //this dialog waits for user input
    if (res != true) Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Show your `XAML` and `C#`. Do you get a `IWebBrowser` Instance  -  Even it isnt loading? How do you set the content - via adress oder with Code behind / VM ?

Comment: Edited. Mapa.html is the google maps example html

Comment: Its just a guess, but I think sometimes your Browser is allready loaded and sometimes it isnt, because your doing ur stuff on the wrong Event.

Comment: I had another apporach - i will try it your way for a solution that fits your needs. I still think that you sometimes use the `Browser` when `!Browser.IsBrowserInitialized`

Comment: I got some new clues. I think you're spot on, the browser is not yet initialized when MetroWindow_Loaded is firing. Gonna try to move that code to Initialized event of Browser

Comment: It's not working. Browser is initialized yet not visible since the MainWindow is halted due to the ShowDialog() of login screen. Therefore Browser.LoadHtml(html) does nothing. I edited with more code

Comment: Maybe try to set the load method on a button and execute it after some seconds to see if  the loading is a problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

Made an ugly workaround that seems to work:

Added event on mainWindow:

```
Activated="MainWindow_OnActivated"


private void MainWindow_OnActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Browser.Address != null) return;
        var html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@".\Resources\Mapa.html");
        Browser.LoadHtml(html);
    }
```

If there's a more elegant solution it'll be welcome

Answer (score 0):

Your title "Cefsharp randomly not initializing" may be misleading. By the way, try setting your browser's *Visibility* property to *Visible*.

I know, this sounds silly. I've met this problem before in WinForms (solved by changing *Visible* property to *true*), not WPF, so I'm not sure if this solution works. But It's worth a try.